# How can I rotate counterclockwise

Tags: c++, math, geometry

This is a function for clockwise rotation. The parameter is how many degrees we want to rotate.
How can I change it to counterclockwise rotation?

```
void rotateClockwise( int degree ) {    
  int currentDegree = getDegree();
  int desiredDegree = currentDegree + degree;
  if( desiredDegree > 359 ) {
    desiredDegree -= 359;
  }
  do {
    newDegree = getDegree(); // Returns current degree
    desiredDegreeSINE = sin(desiredDegree * (PI/180));
    currentDegreeSINE = sin(newDegree * (PI/180));
    if( desiredDegreeSINE > 0 && currentDegreeSINE < 0 ) {
      newDegree = newDegree - 360;
    }
    if( newDegree >= desiredDegree ) {
      // Stop rotating
      break;
    } else {
      // Keep rotating
    }
  } while(true);
}
```

We are rotating 1 degree each moment.

Comment: First, you should use desiredDegree -= 360. And what is the sine for?

Comment: `newDegree < desiredDegree` is not always working. Consider we want to rotate from 350 degrees to 20 degrees. 350 is smaller than 20. That's what sine for.

Comment: How do you make rotation? Surely you could use both negative angles and angles>=360 for rotation, computer isn't afraid them! If you really need `0..359` angle for human reading or for some device, just output `(angle%360)`

Comment: `-= 359` should be `-= 360`

Answer (score 1):

```
void rotateCounterClockwise( int degree ) {
   return rotateClockwise(360 - (360 + degree) % 360);
}
```

Comment: It's not actually a counterclockwise rotation.

Comment: @J.Doe do you have your own definition for counter clockwise?

Answer (score 0):

```
int rotateClockwise(int degree) {
    return (getDegree() + degree) % 360;
}
```

and

```
int rotateCounterClockwise(int degree) {
    int desiredDegree = (getDegree() - degree%360);
    return desiredDegree >= 0 ? desiredDegree : 360+desiredDegree;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplify it.

You already have a direction of rotation - it's the sign of the angle you're rotating through.

```
#include <iostream>

struct thing
{
    int rotate(int alpha)
    {
        angle = (angle + alpha) % 360;
        if (angle < 0)
            angle += 360;

        // by all means pre-calculate sin and cos here if you wish.

        return angle;
    }

    int angle;
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{

    auto t = thing { 10 };

    std::cout << t.rotate( 5 ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << t.rotate( -30 ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << t.rotate( 360 + 30 ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << t.rotate( -360 - 40 ) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

expected results:

```
15
345
15
335
```